# Flags in general position.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, definition

Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space. If i consider two complete flags $\mathcal{V}$ and $\mathcal{W}$ then i know that they are in general position if $V_i \cap W_{n-i}=0$ for all $i$. If i have a number $n >2$ of complete flags, when are they said to be in general position?

Comment: It depends on the circumstances... absent any further information, I would interpret “general position” to mean an unspecified dense open subset of $F(V)^n$, where $F(V)$ is the flag variety.

Comment: @JakeLevinson the circumstance is Pieri's Formula. In particular i am talking about the proof given in "3264 and all that" at page 145. To compute the triple intersection $\sigma_b \sigma_a \sigma_{c^{*}}$, where $\sigma_b$ is a special class and $|a|+b=|c|$, the author considers the Schubert cycles $\Sigma_a(\mathcal{V}),\Sigma_b(\mathcal{U})$ and $\Sigma_{c^*}(\mathcal{W})$ with respect to three general flags $\mathcal{V},\mathcal{U},\mathcal{W}$. It is not clear to me why that is the right way to compute that product between  Schubert classes...

Comment: For that calculation, I think a lot of it comes down to just considering the two non-special Schubert cycles, which is good because it's easier for two flags to be in general position than 3. In particular, *any* two flags that satisfy the condition you gave are equivalent (under change of coordinates) to any two other such flags. Therefore they must be "general enough".

Comment: @JakeLevinson But he starts to consider the intersection $\Sigma_a(\mathcal{V}) \cap \Sigma_{c^*}(\mathcal{U})$ to get the condition $ a_i \leq c_i$ and then considers $\Sigma_a(\mathcal{V}) \cap \Sigma_{c^*}(\mathcal{W}) \cap \Sigma_{b}(U)$ to get $a_{i} \leq c_i \leq a_{i-1}$, where he only cares about the plane $U_{n-k+1-b}$ which (he says) must be general. He doesn't care about the transversality of $\Sigma_{b}(\mathcal{U})$ with respect to the irreducible components of $\Sigma_a(\mathcal{V})\cap \Sigma_{c^*}(\mathcal{W})$.

Comment: So what i think is that for $U_{n-k+1-b}$ general enough, the Schubert cycle $\Sigma_b(\mathcal{U})$ is generically transverse to each irred. component of $\Sigma_a(\mathcal{V})\cap \Sigma_{c^*}(\mathcal{W})$. Is this true?

Comment: Yes, by Kleiman’s Theorem.